# Entity Framework - duplicates handling

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

I am using Entity Framework 6, C#, and MySQL InnoDB as our db engine.

I have the following code to "insert on duplicate update" a record:

```cs
public async Task AddHostIdToGroup(HostsToGroup hostToGroup)
{
    using (var context = new MaintDbContext())
    {
        HostsToGroup htg = context.HostsToGroup.SingleOrDefault(hs => hs.HostId == hostToGroup.HostId);

        if (htg != null)
        {
            htg.GroupId = hostToGroup.GroupId;
            await context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }

        else
        {
            context.HostsToGroup.Add(hostToGroup);
            await context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

The code itself looks fine for `insert on duplicate update`.

Still, on our production server I occasionally see `duplicate errors`.

My initial thought was that it's a race condition issue.

What can I do to prevent these errors, or how should I handle them?

Comment: I had similar issue in WCF service where duplicated records appeared from time to time. And I had to lock the Add/Update method to be use only by 1 thread. Try add a lock to this method or mutex

Comment: you can also use **lock** to restrict only one call to execute the update or insert statements, but this may affect the performance.

Comment: What sort of system is it? Web service/site? A `lock` statement is suitable for neither of these, and it certainly can't be used in an `async` method. It will only help if it's a single user application which might be firing multiple calls to the method.

Comment: obviously I am not going to use a lock, this is not a serious solution

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not necessarily the code but what triggers that code. Say the code is triggered by an ASP.net app button, if a user double clicks on the button then it could shoot off two simultaneous requests that results in double entity creation.

So either fix your front end/entry point to eliminate the double create scenario, push everything into a synchronous service/queue that will allow you to deduplicate or use `Where` instead of `Single` and handle the duplication in code.